# Unir columnas y valores en una sola celda

Tags: r

soy nueva en R, necesito si alguien puede ayudarme ya que estoy muy perdida. Quiero a partir de algo como los valores que muestro a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Armar una tabla como se muestra a continuación, la variable Administracion tiene en una celda a Bueno (valor),Malo(Valor),NC(valor)...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradecería la ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: ¿Pero de que tipo de objeto estamos hablando? ¿matriz? ¿data.frame? ¿una tabla de contingencia?, además ¿de dónde saldrían los valores "Lengua" y "Matemática" si el objeto de entrada no tiene nada de esto? Sería mucho más fácil para los que estamos del otro lado, si compartieras los datos y no una imagen, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta y puedes agregar la estructura de tu "objeto" inicial copiando la salida de este comando `dput(tu_objeto)`, Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

si solo tiene 3 columnas esta funcion te puede servir:

```
   # se crea la funcion para transformar la informacion
   # se crea la funcion para transformar la informacion
   func= function(datos){
   x=as.data.frame(cbind(
        rep(colnames(datos)[1],length(datos[,1])),datos[,1],
        rep(colnames(datos)[2],length(datos[,2])),datos[,2],
        rep(colnames(datos)[3],length(datos[,3])),datos[,3]))}

# se crean los datos para simular una base similar a la de su imagen
bueno.a<- runif(10)
malo.a<- runif(10)
nc.a<- runif(10)
datos.a<-cbind(bueno,malo,nc)
datos.a

           bueno        malo         nc
 [1,] 0.63166594 0.039165835 0.37832280
 [2,] 0.97593263 0.738322392 0.17305483
 [3,] 0.09134683 0.730431445 0.35546118
 [4,] 0.54280093 0.400010729 0.55112279
 [5,] 0.36542496 0.001958678 0.60028709
 [6,] 0.76384828 0.254207359 0.19805927
 [7,] 0.76269985 0.081773635 0.05908256
 [8,] 0.21792653 0.325950074 0.62052376
 [9,] 0.99547950 0.776521560 0.51281435
[10,] 0.93451074 0.498253679 0.64486217

# se aplica la funcion creada anteriormente
y=func(datos.a)

#parece funcionar
y

      [,1]    [,2]                 [,3]   [,4]                 [,5] [,6]                
 [1,] "bueno" "0.631665935739875"  "malo" "0.0391658346634358" "nc" "0.378322802018374" 
 [2,] "bueno" "0.975932630943134"  "malo" "0.738322392338887"  "nc" "0.173054833663628" 
 [3,] "bueno" "0.0913468273356557" "malo" "0.730431445175782"  "nc" "0.355461183236912" 
 [4,] "bueno" "0.542800929164514"  "malo" "0.400010729441419"  "nc" "0.551122788107023" 
 [5,] "bueno" "0.365424958057702"  "malo" "0.0019586777780205" "nc" "0.600287089124322" 
 [6,] "bueno" "0.763848276576027"  "malo" "0.254207359161228"  "nc" "0.198059268528596" 
 [7,] "bueno" "0.762699854327366"  "malo" "0.0817736354656518" "nc" "0.0590825628023595"
 [8,] "bueno" "0.217926526907831"  "malo" "0.325950074242428"  "nc" "0.620523755904287" 
 [9,] "bueno" "0.995479503646493"  "malo" "0.776521560270339"  "nc" "0.512814350426197" 
[10,] "bueno" "0.934510742546991"  "malo" "0.498253679135814"  "nc" "0.644862173590809"
```

Como dijo Patricio Moracho "Lengua" y "Matematica" no se sabe de donde sale por lo que es dificil ponerla en la funcion sin embargo su ud sabe que orden tiene puede utilizar

```
row.names(y)<- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j") #los nombres deben ir entre " " y deben ser la misma cantidad que las filas de la base
y

  [,1]    [,2]                 [,3]   [,4]                 [,5] [,6]                
a "bueno" "0.631665935739875"  "malo" "0.0391658346634358" "nc" "0.378322802018374" 
b "bueno" "0.975932630943134"  "malo" "0.738322392338887"  "nc" "0.173054833663628" 
c "bueno" "0.0913468273356557" "malo" "0.730431445175782"  "nc" "0.355461183236912" 
d "bueno" "0.542800929164514"  "malo" "0.400010729441419"  "nc" "0.551122788107023" 
e "bueno" "0.365424958057702"  "malo" "0.0019586777780205" "nc" "0.600287089124322" 
f "bueno" "0.763848276576027"  "malo" "0.254207359161228"  "nc" "0.198059268528596" 
g "bueno" "0.762699854327366"  "malo" "0.0817736354656518" "nc" "0.0590825628023595"
h "bueno" "0.217926526907831"  "malo" "0.325950074242428"  "nc" "0.620523755904287" 
i "bueno" "0.995479503646493"  "malo" "0.776521560270339"  "nc" "0.512814350426197" 
j "bueno" "0.934510742546991"  "malo" "0.498253679135814"  "nc" "0.644862173590809"
```

Espero te sirva